# Custom Named-Entity Recognition (NER) in product titles using deep learning

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, word-embeddings, named-entity-recognition

I am new to machine learning and Natural Language Processing (NLP). I am trying to identify which brand, product name, dimension, color, ... a product has from its product title. That is, from

'**Sony ZX Series Wired On-Ear Headphones, Black MDR-ZX110**'

I want to extract

'**brand=''Sony''**', '**item=''Headphones''**', '**color=''Black''**', '**model_number=''MDR-ZX110''**'.

I understand that this amounts to something like custom Named-Entity Recognition.

The very minimum of what my algorithm should do is identify the '**item**' attribute value, i.e. it should recognize that the above example refers to ''Headphones''.

My dataset contains product titles such as the one above with appropriate attribute-value pairs scraped from e-commerce websites.

Which deep learning algorithm is best-suited to solve this problem? Which type of input (embeddings?), neural network model, output layer should I choose to start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am currently working on a similar project but limited only to brand detection in product titles, the task is a named entity recognition task and can be solved by different models, the most used ones are BI-LSTM + CRF (Bidirection LSTM with a CRF layer on top). You could try to use spaCy for the task which has a nice documentation and good workflow to train NER models. Or you can build the model yourself using [tensorflow](https://guillaumegenthial.github.io/sequence-tagging-with-tensorflow.html) (here is a good tutorial) or [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/nlp/advanced_tutorial.html) (there is a tutorial here)

Obviously, you will need annotated data to train your models.

Here are some papers that might help you get some insights (at least they did for me) :

- [Sequence tagging with BI-LSTM CRF](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.01991)
- [Product name detection in user generated content (a bit old)](https://keg.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn/jietang/publications/ICDM12-Wu-et-al-Product-mention-recognition.pdf)

**Edit**

You can find my project which is similar to yours here with pretrained models: https://github.com/annis-souames/brand-ner

Here's a second project on Github :
https://github.com/maciej-cecot/brand-detection

Comment: What are the pros and cons of using spaCy to train a BiLSTM-CRF model over TensorFlow or PyTorch? Which input embedding is useful for such a model?

Comment: spaCy is much easier to use and train models than tensor flow or PyTorch, if you don't have much experience in DL, I recommend to go with spaCy or Flair as they make things much easier. I updated the original questions to the project I've been working on and some links